# Smartly enforcing type of parameter based on config object

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure what to call this so please bare with my while I describe it.

I have three config objects:

```
const configA = {
    type: 'A' as const,
    getPath: (query: { foo: string }) => `/${query.foo}`
}

const configB = {
    type: 'B' as const,
    getPath: (query: {}) => `/path/b`
}

const configC = {
    type: 'C' as const,
    getPath: (query: {bar: number}) => `/c/${query.bar}`
}
```

I combine these into one master record like this:

```
const CONFIGS = {
    [configA.type]: configA,
    [configB.type]: configB,
    [configC.type]: configC
}
```

I now want to write a function who's arguments respect the configs above. So that type safety is provided. So with the above if I did this:

```
add({
    type: 'C',
    query: { foo: true }
})
```

Typescript should warn me that if the `type` is `C` that the `query` object here is invalid. However it doesn't warn me.

I tried this:

```
function add(inputs: {
    type: (typeof CONFIGS)[keyof typeof CONFIGS]['type'],
    query: Parameters<(typeof CONFIGS)[keyof typeof CONFIGS]['getPath']>[0]
}) {
 const config = CONFIGS[inputs.type];
 if (!config) {
    throw new Error('Config not found');
 }

 const url = 'mysite.blah' + config.getPath(inputs.query); // inputs.query is getting Typescript warning

 console.log('url:', url);
}
```

However it's not working, and it has the added problem that `inputs.query` on the line where I do `config.getPath(inputs.query)` is throwing this Typescript error:

> Argument of type '{} | { foo: string; } | { bar: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ foo: string; } & { bar: number; }'.

Here is my full code: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzAgjAvDA3gKBkJigE8AHAUwC4YByNWmAQwjnGgBoCiUKoAFJlAAWNABQBHAK4UATiRo4YCECBrRZSMChgBfAJRYAfDAAGAegAkOaXJIA6FSF2m8uvHnjQ2iVACEsXG5CUkoaWj9GFh9OYJheASFRGEkZeUUDYzNzMiTzACNXd092WHhkFABhQPwiYnJqOkqo1i8oLjqEwRFxW3TcfKZZGjApAFt8uUzMEwtgKxs0h0HZFzcPNphKgHkAOQAxAEkAcQBlGriAbXLUNHtQigBdGhv0DqJr8Aq-e4bnn2+70In18VV+lH+r0q6zwCCkYGAUCQ4GYABNUWItGQpFAIIo4g9xA8QAgtnsjmd9JcANYUEgk+qUBk7A4nU6PS60B60R5AmB9BQwQSyJhjPhyCAAHjExNJLIppyptPppNlZNZZw5tC6SR5RkuAAZHm5DLVNq9AvK2ZcsTiIOCngBuAhIUliACEr1NBOEshAAHcYGAKIGAKKyP2yMS0SpfVBBkCwFTw1G0fTOvQeGKwKSyAA2gVoYxIECQUAo9nyeaYwkYAGoAah7DqRJiwNjcfYBems14QHmK3mQCho7m81RaBwYGOe8UmOixLUiISmpO4gLFMpVDQoLIZJmDEA)

What is this technique called? Is it possible to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: TS doesn't deal well with what I call "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The recommended way to deal with this is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involved refactoring operations to be generic indexed accesses into mapped types.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQ4xW) for how that looks for your example code.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh wow thank you @jcalz I'm still studying this, but yes please. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks also for sharing "correlated unions" with me, I was having such a hard time searching the search engines for this technique.

Comment: @jcalz Would it ever be worth creating a `typescript-correlated-unions` tag (name open to change...) for these questions? Using the SO search, I see [53 results for "correlated union"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22correlated%20union%22) and [34 for "correlated unions"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22correlated%20unions%22).

Comment: Yeah maybe?  I don't know if the term is in use generally enough... I mean, *I* call it that but I don't know that others would search for it or tag it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call signature for `add` isn't type safe because the `type` and `query` properties of the `inputs` parameter are independent of each other.  Both are [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) which could each be any of the (three) possibile values.  You could fix this by making the type of `inputs` a single union so that `type` and `query` are correlated with each other:

```
type Inputs = {
    [P in keyof typeof CONFIGS]: {
        type: P,
        query: Parameters<typeof CONFIGS[P]["getPath"]>[0]
    }
}[keyof typeof CONFIGS]

/* type Inputs = 
  { type: "A"; query: { foo: string; }; } | 
  { type: "B"; query: {}; } | 
  { type: "C"; query: { bar: number; }; } */

declare function add(inputs: Inputs): void;

add({ type: 'C', query: { foo: true } }); // error!
add({ type: 'C', query: { bar: 123 } }); // okay
```

That fixes your problem from the caller's side.  Unfortunately the implementation has essentially the same error:

```
function add(inputs: Inputs) {
    const config = CONFIGS[inputs.type];
    if (!config) {
        throw new Error('Config not found');
    }
    const url = 'mysite.blah' + config.getPath(inputs.query); // error!
    console.log('url:', url);
};
```

---

That's because TypeScript lacks direct support for what I call "correlated unions" as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  When the compiler type checks a single block of code like the body of `add()`, it does so *once*.  And from the *types* of the expressions inside the body alone, there's not enough information to verify what you're doing as safe.  Yes, `inputs` has to be of the right type, but when you try to use it twice like `CONFIGS[inputs.type].getPath(inputs.query)`, the compiler can't follow the thread.  If it could analyze that code *three times*, once for each union narrowing, it would work.  But it can only do so once.

The recommended approach for dealing with this is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring so that instead of unions, the operations are expressed in terms of a simple key-value type and [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type and into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type. The goal is to make it so `CONFIGS[input.type].getPath` is seen as a single function (not a union) whose parameter is the same generic type as that of `input.query`.

The refactoring could look like this:

First let's rename `CONFIGS` out of the way, since we need its type to change:

```
const _CONFIGS = {
    [configA.type]: configA,
    [configB.type]: configB,
    [configC.type]: configC
}
```

Then we'll use it to build our simple key-value type:

```
type QueryMap = { [K in keyof typeof _CONFIGS]: 
  Parameters<typeof _CONFIGS[K]["getPath"]>[0] 
}

/* type QueryMap = {
    A: { foo: string; };
    B: {};
    C: { bar: number;};
} */
```

We'll use the `QueryMap` type as the basis for the relationships involved here.  You could have started with this as a manually-written type and defined `CONFIGS` in terms of it, but this is easier to scale, since it will automatically update if you add members.

Now we'll rewrite the type of `CONFIGS` as a mapped type on `QueryMap`:

```
type Configs = { [K in keyof QueryMap]: { type: K, getPath: (query: QueryMap[K]) => string } };
```

And say that `CONFIGS` is of that type:

```
const CONFIGS: Configs = _CONFIGS; // okay
```

The assignment succeeds, so the compiler is able to see the equivalence between `typeof _CONFIGS` and `Configs`.  And now we can rewrite `add()` to be a generic function in `K extends keyof Configs`:

```
function add<K extends keyof Configs>(inputs: { type: K, query: QueryMap[K] }) {
    const config = CONFIGS[inputs.type];
    if (!config) {
        throw new Error('Config not found');
    }

    const url = 'mysite.blah' + config.getPath(inputs.query); // okay

    console.log('url:', url);
}
```

This now works. It's subtle, because if you replace `CONFIGS` with `_CONFIGS` in the first line of the function, the error will come back.  Yes, the types of those are equivalent, but they are not treated identically by the compiler.  The `Configs` type is expressed as a mapped type over `QueryMap`, and `inputs` also has a type depending on `QueryMap`, and this correspondence can be used to type check the function.  The type of `_CONFIGS` is not expressed with respect to `QueryMap`, so the compiler doesn't see the generic connection between it and `inputs`.

Oh and the callers still get the behavior you wanted too:

```
add({ type: 'C', query: { foo: true } }); // error!
add({ type: 'C', query: { bar: 123 } }); // okay
```

---

There you go.  This refactoring is about as close to compiler-verified type safety for your `add()` implementation as you can get.  I'm not sure it's necessarily worth it; if you don't care about the compiler checking your code in the implementation you could just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to silence it:

```
function add(inputs: Inputs) {
    const config = CONFIGS[inputs.type];
    if (!config) {
        throw new Error('Config not found');
    }
    const url = 'mysite.blah' + config.getPath(inputs.query as any); // okay
    console.log('url:', url);
};
```

which is a lot easier to do.  It all depends on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-E0yhtPUvw9JgAzfCqYyKFMwyqk2PBHhgABFFYAFkmDIGpLIAaX+MAgRBKFpRgRT4TldE8WGCkoCpWkGihCLGVRb4-NZDk+G6YRuV5AVdzwZVVTczzvJUuo0DNSiYA0LQUGjOI-B9OJKj44Zw0mORDRw3QYFjDwXIXaz3gGdLAuCyVSrsLyyG0jjGj89C32SVJeOm+RZvStFZhMOrtHE5tyyUlEaGGipRpSqLmzwRNk1TdM2OpAKKBueKwAzVgJXpByICMD88zNXUlp4-p3Jm7ztpmII6nLdSq0ims6zeWymziNsUi7Bzex3Adh1HccYCnGc53O1BRxXc1103bdhVwwh9yPE8zwveLr1ve8YCfdTX2ypIAa-FYsLiLwYLghCkKPVD0Mw5tijYwjXS4sjvQGGrqOOPqJKAkCmJAWQWIVhaSO48jBg6wTRPEwCGOkyCtiAA)

Comment: Sorry, I had a follow up question, please disregard if I'm abusing the attention here. I was playing more with it to fit my use case. It's unrelated to the correlated union, I probably should ask another question, please let me know, but I think my line 2 is causing issues of "string cannot be used as an index" - https://tsplay.dev/w6GP0N - do you know how to make that not be a string but like "constant"?

Comment: Yes, that's a problem; either add a type parameter to `TQstashEnqueueConfig` to allow for narrower `type`s, or don't *annotate* the variables as that type but instead use something like [the `satisfies` operator](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator). But yeah, this is out of scope for this question and I'm not inclined to dive into followups here.  If you continue to have issues you should consider posting a new question and then maybe I will look at it (and if not, someone else *might* whereas the chance for that here is much lower).

Comment: Sorry about that, really appreciate your still replying!